# How to corectly use json method in javascript?

Tags: json

I am trying to display the count of datapasar object and the value at the second index of datapasar.
I think javascript will display ' nama pasar: pasar losari jumlah data:5 '
but the browser not displaying anything.This is my script:

```
var datapasar = {
  "datapasar": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "nama": "pasar bandung"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "nama": "pasar losari"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "nama": "pasar losari 2"
    }
  ]
};

alert('nama pasar:'+ datapasar[1]['nama'] + 'kota :' +'jumlah data'+ datapasar.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case it would look like this:

```
var datapasar = {
  "datapasar": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "nama": "pasar bandung"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "nama": "pasar losari"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "nama": "pasar losari 2"
    }
  ]
};

alert('nama pasar:'+ datapasar.datapasar[1]['nama'] + 'kota :' +'jumlah data'+ datapasar.datapasar.length);
```

`datapasar` is the name of your variable and the first and only key of your object which contains an array.